# Recovering deleted files from Google Drive

Tags: data-recovery, google-drive

I installed Google Drive on a new laptop and waited till all the files to upload but the new laptop didn't have enough space so I deleted the files without realising that it will affect the files on my original Google Drive. Is there a way to back date Google drive so that I could access all the files I managed to delete. Please!

Comment: So you're trying to recover those folders you mean?

Answer (score 1):

The files should still be in **Trash.**

1. Go to drive.google.com
2. Click **Trash** in the left navigation.
3. Locate the item you'd like to move back to Google Drive, and check the box next to the title.
4. Click the **More** drop-down menu.
5. Select **Restore from trash.** This will restore the item back to the owner’s Google Drive, as well as to any collaborator’s Google Drive.

[More info.](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/MmLIIRp9tbI)